# Is there any clock view in android whose time can be set in activity

Tags: android, time, clock

I am actually searching for an android clock view whose time can be set in the activity and then it will start working from that setted time.I saw the TextClock view but it seemed that only the timezone can be set.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use this class, might help you, You can change date time whatever you want

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


import java.util.Calendar;



public class DigitalClock extends AppCompatTextView {

    Calendar mCalendar;
    private FormatChangeObserver mFormatChangeObserver;

    private Runnable mTicker;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private boolean mTickerStopped = false;

    String mFormat;

    public DigitalClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initClock();
    }

    public DigitalClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initClock();
    }

    private void initClock() {
        if (mCalendar == null) {
            mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        mTickerStopped = false;
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        mFormatChangeObserver = new FormatChangeObserver();
        getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mFormatChangeObserver);
        setFormat();

        mHandler = new Handler();


        mTicker = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mTickerStopped) return;
                mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                setText(DateFormat.format(mFormat, mCalendar));
                invalidate();
                long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
            }
        };
        mTicker.run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        mTickerStopped = true;
        getContext().getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(
                mFormatChangeObserver);
    }

    private void setFormat() {
        mFormat = "dd MMM yy , hh:mm ss a ";
    }




    private class FormatChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public FormatChangeObserver() {
            super(new Handler());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            setFormat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
        //noinspection deprecation
        return DigitalClock.class.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: I  haven't learn kotlin yet ,so is there any java version of this?

Comment: Hi, I've posted in Java now.pls check

Comment: Is this the class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock which you are referring to ?

Comment: Its Similar to this class. But you can't change Date Format in  DigitalClock (developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock).